# Does anyone know how to fix the issue not having the hydrogen atoms accounted for when converting to a .mol file?

Tags: export, chemistry, ocr

Hi I am using moleculeRecognize function to upload structures from images and I am attempting to convert the structures in .mol files. However every time I convert to .mol files the hydrogen atoms in the structures are not being accounted for. I was wondering if anyone has any way to overcome this.

Comment: Could you please include a sample image and the exact code you use? Paste the code in your question as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  Start with a suitable image.  For example,

```
img = Image@MoleculePlot@Import@First@
      FileNames["aspirin.mol", $InstallationDirectory, 6];
Show[img, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

Now, apply `MoleculeRecognize` to the image and export the results as a .mol file with the `IncludeHydrogens` option, like this

```
Export["tmp.mol", MoleculeRecognize[img],
  "MOL", IncludeHydrogens -> True];
Import[%, "Text"]
```

[image]

There is more to the .mol file than is shown above.  Notice the 7 hydrogens at the end of the atom list.